# How long does it take for a satellite to reach MEO?

Tags: launch, orbit, time

I'm just wondering how long it takes satellites from launch to orbiting in MEO.

Comment: This is a very broad question, that can vary considerably depending on the exact type of orbit, rocket, fuel spent, etc. You could ask for something like the shortest orbit to a GPS satellite's orbit, for instance, but as this stands, it's a bit broad.

Answer (score 2):

It will vary quite a bit with the exact MEO orbit and launcher used, but typically it would be something like:

- 10-15 minutes launch from surface to a MEO transfer orbit
- Coasting to apogee, anywhere from half an hour to several hours
- Circularization burn taking a few minutes

That gets the satellite into the desired orbit, but the satellite's mission may require it to be in a particular position in that orbit as well; depending on the satellite's capabilities, the phasing maneuvers could take days or even weeks (for ion thruster-powered sats, e.g.) to carry out.

Here's [a typical example](http://spaceflight101.com/atlas-v-gps-iif11/launch-profile/) of a launch to 20,000km circular orbit inclined at 55º:

- ~4 minutes ascent on the first stage
- ~13 minutes on the second stage
- 3 hour coast to apogee
- about 1.5 minute circularization burn